# Using fonts in a webpage

Tags: html, webfonts

When I use fonts on my webpage, I either use Google Fonts or fonts that are installed on my system. I wanted to know, if it's possible to have a folder with fonts saved in the same folder as the index file, and use those fonts in the webpage without having to install them on the system.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Yes, if you have the correct formats (and the correct license)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webfonts that live on your server alongside your html and css by referencing them in your css file:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "myFont";
    src: url("myFont.ttf");
}
```

then you can use it as you would a google web font:

```css
html {
    font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold", serif;
}
```

More information and examples (including the ones I used) can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts).